# Need guidance in using Spark for publishing data to Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to write a spark java code for publishing messages to kafka topic. Its working as expected. However, the amount of time it takes to load data is on similar scale to Naive approach.

Can you help me understand if I m missing out something?

**Spark producer way:**

```
public void loadInputDataToKafka(JavaRDD<Customer> inputData)
  {

    inputData.foreachPartition(customerIterator -> {
      Properties properties = getKafkaConfiguration();
      Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

      while(customerIterator.hasNext()) {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("testTopic", 
            null, customerIterator.next().toString())).get();
      }
      producer.close();
    });
  }
```

**Naive Approach:**

```
public void loadInputDataToKafka(JavaRDD<Customer> inputData)
      {

        Properties properties = getKafkaConfiguration();
        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

        List<Customer> customerList = inputData.collect();
        for(Customer customer:customerList) {
          try {
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("testTopic", 
                null, customer.toString())).get();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            producer.close();
            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
          } 
        }
```

Time taken to load 80K records using approach 1 and 2 are on similar scale (150 seconds). Am I not using spark partitions in the right way? If no, what is the advantage that I get out of spark vs going for a regular iteration?

Comment: What is your partitioning strategy and are your partitions evenly distributed?

Comment: I m running them locally. Not running in cluster as of now.

Comment: Then I would expect it to perform identically (or nearly so). Think about it, your partition size is effectively 1.

Comment: If possible, can you throw some light on how my partition strategy should be  and how i can possibly find a significant performance improvement for the same 80k records ? all what I need to do is, read 80k records and publish the same to kafka topic.

Comment: If you have n nodes in your cluster, you want your partitions to be around x / n where x is the total number of records.

Comment: @Vikram: if  you are running your spark job on multi node cluster, you would get some advantage, otherwise both will take some time.

Comment: Thank you Elliott and Shankar